# Toshiba Satellite Laptop Realtek Network Driver Error code (10)?

Tags: windows-vista, laptop, 64-bit

hello all i have a Toshiba 64 bit windows vista, i tried looking for the drivers from the main website but no luck all the ones i got did not work or did not do anything. would someone know where i can find it or maybe fix this issue it will not find any network wireless or even if i hook up the Ethernet cable. i don't know why Toshiba makes it hard they should have a complete bundle.

**Model: A305-S687**